# Undefined index: images.jpg [APP\Controller\PostController.php, line 19]

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/add.ctp -->
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->file('Post.Image');
echo $this->Form->input('Post.name', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
<!-- File: /app/Controler/PostControler.php -->
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post') ) {  
        $filename=$this->request->data('Post.Image');
        $filename = "app/webroot/img/uploads/".$_FILES[$filename]['name'];(line 19)
        $tempname=$this->request->data('Post.Image');
        if((move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$tempname]['tmp_name'],$filename))){ (line 21)
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('save images successful.'));
                redirect();
                $this->redirect('/posts/upload');
        }}else{
         $this->Session->setFlash(__('not save images.'));}
     }
}
```

the code above 2 error

```
Undefined index: images.jpg [APP\Controller\PostsController.php, line 19]
Undefined index: images.jpg [APP\Controller\PostsController.php, line 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error, but I solved it. Here is my view and controller code related to image. The column name in my database table is "picture".

view file form  input tag

```
<?php  
echo $this->Form->file('picture', array('class'=>'form-control'));  
?>
```

controller file :: PostController.php

```
public function addNewPost() {
    $this->layout = false;
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->data;            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); die;

        if (!empty($data['Post']['picture']['name'])) {
            $file = $data['Post']['picture'];

            $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1);
            $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif','png');

            if (in_array($ext, $arr_ext)) {

                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img/postimages/' . $file['name']);
                $this->request->data['Post']['picture'] = $file['name'];
                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); die;     
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please upload a valid image.'), 'default', array('id' => 'flashMessage', 'class' => 'alert alert-danger'), 'error');
            }
        }
        $path = $data['Post']['picture']['name'];
        if(isset($path)){
            $data['Post']['picture'] ='postimages/' . $path;
        }
        $data['Post']['picture'] ='postimages/default.jpg'; 
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); die;
        if ($this->Post->save($data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Congrats !!! Post Published to our blog. Thanks for posting.'), 'default', array('id' => 'flashMessage', 'class' => 'alert alert-success'), 'success');
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'addNewPost'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Post could not be published. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('id' => 'flashMessage', 'class' => 'alert alert-danger'), 'error');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's working perfectly for me without any error. i  am using cakePHP  ver 2.7.5  right now.